# Error in sum of array using recursion (Compilation and runtime)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, runtime-error

I was asked to do sum of numbers in an array using recursion where sample input would be provided and the compiler gave me the following errors   (note, I tried three ways and got the corresponding errors). Can someone please explain to me what I was doing wrong here?

**Error for Code 1**

```
In file included from Runner.cpp:2:0:
Solution.h: In function 'int sum(int*, int)':
Solution.h:7:32: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]
     totalsum = totalsum + sum(n+1,n-1);
                                ^
Solution.h:1:5: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'int sum(int*, int)'
 int sum(int input[], int n) {
     ^
```

**Error for code 2**

```
Solution.h: In function 'int sum(int*, int)':
Solution.h:5:24: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]
return input[0] + sum(n+1,n-1);
                    ^
Solution.h:1:5: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'int sum(int*, int)'
int sum(int input[], int n) { 
 ^
```

**Error for code 3**

```
Runtime error
```

**Code 1**

```
int sum(int input[], int n) { 
if (n<=0)
{
    return 0;
};
int totalsum;
totalsum = totalsum + sum(n+1,n-1);
return totalsum;
}
```

**Code 2**

```
if (n<=0)
 return 0;
return input[0] + sum(n+1,n-1);
```

**Code 3**

```
 if (n <= 0) 
    return 0; 
return (sum(input, n +1) + input[n - 1]);
```

Comment: You probably want `sum(input + 1, n - 1)` instead of `sum(n+1,n-1)`... but it is not the only issue.

Comment: In your function `sum(...)`, `input` is an int array, but then you call it using `n+1`, which is an int. You also use `totalsum` without initializing it.

Answer (score 1):

In this function implementation

```
int sum(int input[], int n) { 
if (n<=0)
{
    return 0;
};
int totalsum;
totalsum = totalsum + `sum(n+1,n-1)`;
return totalsum;
}
```

the first parameter declared like `int input[]` has the type `int *`. However instead of the array you are passing the integer `n + 1` as an argument in the recursive call

```
sum(n+1,n-1)
```

The same problem exists in this code snippet

```
if (n<=0)
 return 0;
return input[0] + sum(n+1,n-1);
```

In the second code snippet it seems there is access memory beyond the array

```
return (sum(input, n +1) + input[n - 1]); 
                   ^^^^
```

And moreover the call has an infinite recursion because the second argument is always increased: `n + 1`.

The function can be written like

```
long long int sum( const int a[], size_t n ) 
{
    return n == 0 ? 0 : a[0] + sum( a + 1, n - 1 );
}
```

Another approach is the following

```
long long int sum( const int a[], size_t n ) 
{
    return n == 0 ? 0 : 
                  ( n == 1 : a[0] ? sum( a, n / 2 ) + sum( a + n / 2, n - n / 2 ) );
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

long long int sum( const int a[], size_t n )
{
    return n == 0 ? 0
                  : ( n == 1 ? a[0] : sum( a, n / 2 ) + sum( a + n / 2, n - n / 2 ) );
}

int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2,3, 4,5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    std::cout << sum( a, N ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
55
```

Comment: Possibly [std::size(a)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) (since C++17) instead of `sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a )`.

Comment: @Jarod42 For beginners it is better to use sizeof.

Comment: I would disagree, as `std::size` won't compile inside `sum` whereas `sizeof` gives wrong result. pro of `sizeof` is compatibility with older standards though.

Comment: @Jarod42 They should start learning the language from its basics.

Answer (score 0):

For error for code 1, you are using an integer variable where it is expecting an array. To correct this, you would need to make n an index of some array. so the call would be something like `sum(index[n+1], n-1)` . Reason being is that arrays are pointers, pointers are arrays. so unless you have a pointer to an `int` variable, it will not work.